# SQL queries - For Customer and Sale representative

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

Q: List the numbers and names of all customers who are represented by Ann Hull but who do not currently have orders on file.

This is what I have so far... but it isn't the right output:

```
CREATE TABLE REP (
  REP_NUM char(2) PRIMARY KEY,
  LAST_NAME char(15),
  FIRST_NAME char(15),
  STREET char(15),
  CITY char(15),
  PROVINCE char(3),
  ZIP char(5),
  COMMISSION decimal(7, 2),
  RATE decimal(3, 2)
);
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
  CUSTOMER_NUM char(3) PRIMARY KEY,
  CUSTOMER_NAME char(35) NOT NULL,
  STREET char(15),
  CITY char(15),
  PROVINCE char(3),
  ZIP char(5),
  BALANCE decimal(8, 2),
  CREDIT_LIMIT decimal(8, 2),
  REP_NUM char(2)
);
CREATE TABLE ORDERS (
  ORDER_NUM char(5) PRIMARY KEY,
  ORDER_DATE date,
  CUSTOMER_NUM char(3)
);

CREATE TABLE PART (
  PART_NUM char(4) PRIMARY KEY,
  DESCRIPTION char(15),
  ON_HAND decimal(4, 0),
  CLASS char(2),
  WAREHOUSE char(1),
  PRICE decimal(6, 2)
);
CREATE TABLE ORDER_LINE (
  ORDER_NUM char(5),
  PART_NUM char(4),
  NUM_ORDERED decimal(3, 0),
  QUOTED_PRICE decimal(6, 2),
  PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_NUM, PART_NUM)
);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: "*This is what I have so far.*" - there is no SELECT statement there. Only the table definitions (which is good)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER c
LEFT JOIN REP r
ON c.REP_NUM = r.REP_NUM
LEFT JOIN ORDERS o
ON o.CUSTOMER_NUM = c.CUSTOMER_NUM 
WHERE o.CUSTOMER_NUM ISNULL
AND r.FIRST_NAME = 'Ann Hull'
```

Hope the above helps, It should work with minor modifications to the where clause especially combining the first and last names.

Answer (score 0):

Filter the Rep table on firstname and lastname for Ann Hull and join it with the Rep table on the rep_num fields. To only return customers with no orders use a subquery to check that no orders exists (NOT EXISTS) in the Order table for a customer.

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER c
JOIN REP r
ON c.REP_NUM = r.REP_NUM
AND r.FIRSTNAME = 'Ann'
AND r.LASTNAME = 'Hull'
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ORDERS o WHERE o.CUSTOMER_NUM = c.CUSTOMER_NUM)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18927333)

Comment: I have added a description of my solution to accompany the code. I hope this improves the value of my answer.

Comment: @ADM, sorry but I don't understand your comment.